# Why does Ubuntu use Python 2.6 and not 3.X?

Tags: python

I have recently started learning Python and thus have learned that Ubuntu (10.10) uses Python 2.6. It seems to me that Python 3.X is still rather unpopular in the Linux/Ubuntu community.

Why is that?

**Edit April 30, 2012**
Python 3.2 is not shipped by default in Ubuntu. There are plans to make Python 3.2 default in 12.10, however, and make it the only version shipped by then. Python 2.7 will then not be on the default ISO anymore. Note: this is only envisaged, not certain yet.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/FoundationsQPythonVersions

Comment: Is 3.2 shipped with 11.10? It still appears to be 2.7, although 3.x is available in the repositories.

Comment: As a matter of fact BOTH are shipped. If you want to use python 2.7, just type `$ python` in your terminal, for using 3.2 do `$ python3`.

Comment: If I type `python3` I get _The program 'python3' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python3-minimal_

Comment: Can you try `$ python 3.2` then? If that does not work I am mistaken, sorry. But in 12.04 there surely is Pyton 3 inlcuded.

Comment: http://www.wefearchange.org/2011/05/python-plans-for-ubuntu-1110-and-1204.html

Comment: Same message, not installed. You have probably installed it at one point or another. It's not in by default on 11.10

Comment: There are some news. See my edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think Python 3 is less popular, it just haven't been around as long..

For a language to be used adoption time is needed, version 3.* is so much different from 2.* that you can't use the modules/extensions without changing them beforehand. Therefore all modules that the current infrastructure depends on needs to be ported python 3.*

"If you don't know which version to use, start with Python 2.7; more existing third party software is compatible with Python 2 than Python 3 right now." -Python.org download page.

Se also: [Python 2 or Python 3](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python)

Comment: Some news: Python 3 is now shipped!

Answer (score 6):

see http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Answer (score 5):

Because Python 3 is still under development and until now a lot of libraries are not ported to Python 3.

Comment: Python 3 is not under development, it's as released as 2.6 (so is 3.1). The real issue is that a lot of libraries are not ported yet.

Comment: Python 3 is under development... that doesn't mean that there can't be releases that can be considered stable. but i wouldn't consider 3.2 alpha 3 stable as you imply.